# How can I get that active true value?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function, object, react-props

const expand = (id) =>{
activate.map((isActive) => id && isActive.active ? isActive.active = false : activate.active = true)
setActivate(activate)

}

Answer (score 0):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) doesn't mutate an array it returns a new array.

Is this what you want ?

```
const expand = (id) => { 
   const activateClone = activate.map((isActive) => id && isActive.active ? isActive.active = false : activate.active = true) 
   setActivate(activateClone)
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I want to toggle and get  the value of isActive.active through props